# Continuing to receive Trello email notifications even after "Unsubscribing"

Tags: trello, email, notifications

I'm tracking the Trello Development board but the email notifications were starting to be a pain and I couldn't figure how to disable email notifications on a per-board basis, so I went and unsubscribed (unchecked "Subscribe" in options).

However, I'm still receiving email notifications from Trello?  This is... curious.  I've disabled Email Notifications completely for now, but is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

(I do have the board "Pinned to Header Menu" so that I can easily view it.)